# Как использовать пакет translateR

Tags: r

Проблема с `translate()` из пакета `translateR`

Простой код:

```
library(translateR)
translate(dataset = NULL, 
          content.field = NULL, 
          content.vec = 'Hi', 
          google.api.key = NULL, 
          microsoft.client.id = my.microsoft.client.id, 
          microsoft.client.secret = my.microsoft.client.secret, 
          source.lang = 'no', 
          target.lang = 'de')
```

выдает ошибку:

> Error in `translate(dataset = NULL, content.field = NULL, content.vec = "Hi",` : unused arguments `(dataset = NULL, content.field = NULL, content.vec = "Hi", google.api.key = NULL, microsoft.client.id = my.microsoft.client.id, microsoft.client.secret = my.microsoft.client.secret, source.lang = "no", target.lang = "de")`

Подскажите, что не так в моем коде.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно Help:

> microsoft.client.id   --- To use the Microsoft API, a client id and a
>   client secret value must be provided. For more information on getting
>   these, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx.
>   NOTE: you do not need to obtain an access token. translateR will
>   retrieve a token internally.
>
> microsoft.client.secret   --- To use the Microsoft API, a client id and
>   a client secret value must be provided. For more information on
>   getting these, see
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx. The client
>   secret value is a unique identifying string obtained when registering
>   with Microsoft (see the link for more information). NOTE: you do not
>   need to obtain an access token. translateR will retrieve a token
>   internally.

Ты должен присвоить объектам microsoft.client.id и microsoft.client.secret информацию о своем id и секретном коде, которые тебе присвоил Майкрософт.